# How to validate Yup.date() without selecting any dates?

Tags: javascript, yup

```
Yup.object().shape({date: Yup.date().required('Date is required!')});
```

Suppose I select this field, but navigate away without picking a date. Is it possible to validate this field with an empty date?

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is to use a default date when none is provided, replace `.required()` with `.default()`

```js
Yup.date().default(() => new Date())
```

Comment: It's not working if i am using react-hook-form